# How to implement a referral system in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, e-commerce, referrals

I'm trying to develop a ecommerce application where referral system will be integrated. I want to onboard users using my referral link.
Now there exists two scenarios - one, user whom I shared the link has app installed on his device. Second, user does not have app installed on his device. The first scenario is easy to implement. In the second case, when the user clicks on the link, it redirects him to the Play Store and ask him to install the app. After installation, when the user tries to sign up, I want him to get signed up using my referral link which I shared. How can I fetch the referral link details after I install the app from the Play Store.

I've found multiple solutions but all of them where using Firebase dynamic links but I want to implement my own system. How can I do that? Also if there exists any alternative other than firebase, please do mention.

Comment: You have to use deep linking for that. 1. Firebase dynamic links are also a good option 2. adjust_sdk is also a good option